# Windows 10 shareing issuse

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-shares

I have some computers on a small network in same Workgroup and they can ping server.

Server operating system : Windows 10 pro

Category One clients : Windows 10 Enterprise

Category Two clients : Windows 7

After i active "turn off password protected sharing" on server :

Category One clients can not access shared folder on server and get "windows cannot access \\Server" error message.
Category Two clients are ok and have access to shared folder

Can anyone help me to figure out Why Windows 10 clients can not access share folder when "password protected sharing" is off ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone help me to figure out Why Windows 10 clients can not access
> share folder when "password protected sharing" is off ?

Increased security in modern versions of Windows 10 (within the last 12 months) require passwords, especially Windows 10 Enterprise and (for future) Windows 11.

So the best answer here is to enable Passwords on all your machines and then normal file sharing setups should work fine.

I share folders between Windows 10 Pro machines with no difficulty.